# Random point 2D with limits

Tags: c#, loops, vector, random, coordinates

I need to generate a 1000 random numbers as [x,y] coordinates. The highest x value is 76, while for y it is 15. I have also made a Point 2D class which should read the X and Y coorinates and do some math equations (the class is called Punkt2D, and it uses X and Y like distance.X and distance.Y to calculate).

For now I only get 1000 random numbers between 0 to 75. How do I turn it into coordinate values?

(kolonner means columns, rader mens rows and nummer mens number).

```
public const int MaxX = 76;
        public const int MaxY = 15;
        public const int min = 0;
        public const int rader = 1000;
        public const int kolonner = 2;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int[,] nummer = new int[kolonner,rader];
            for (int m = 0; m < kolonner; m++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
                {
                    nummer[m,n] = r.Next(0,MaxX);
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(nummer[m, n]));
                }
            }
        }
```

I did also start on this method here, where I removed the loops.

```
int row = r.Next(nummer.GetLength(0));
            int column = r.Next(nummer.GetLength(1));
            int randomNummer = nummer[row, column];
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(nummer));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "turn it into coordinate values"? Do your coordinate values have decimal places or do you just want it to be able to select negative numbers?

Comment: int[,] is the wrong datatype, you need a tuple<int,int> and generate it with new tuople<int,int(r.Next(0,76),r.Next(0,15))

Comment: A `List<Point> ` may also do.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to generate random points. Let's assume ranges of `x = {0..M-1}` and `y = {0..N-1}`

1. Create two separate random numbers `int x = random.Next(M); int y = random.Next(N)`. The lower bound is `0`. Note that the upper bound is exclusive. Therefore `M` and `N` must be 1 higher than the maximum values. They represent the number of possible values along one axis (the number of pixels in an image).

   ```
   const int M = 77, Y = 16; // Gives range of { 0..76, 0..15 }.
   ```
2. Generate one random value `int r = random.Next(M * N);` and then get the coordinates with `int x = r % M; int y = r / M;` (`%` is the modulo operator yielding the remainder of the division).

You can get a point with:

```
var p = new Point(x, y);
```